Is every subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ a union of a set in $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})\otimes\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ and a Lebesgue null set?
Let $\Sigma_1\otimes\Sigma_2$ denote the product $\sigma$-algebra of $\Sigma_1$ and $\Sigma_2$. Let $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ denote respectively the $\sigma$-algebra of Lebesgue measurable sets of $\mathbb{R}^d$ and the powerset of $\mathbb{R}^d$. It is well known that even though $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^2)\neq\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R})\otimes\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R})$, we have that $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ is the completion of $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R})\otimes\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R})$, as it is actually the completion of $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2) = \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\otimes\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$.
Whether $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^2)=\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})\otimes\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ or not is independent of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ (see here), but I think we could ask if $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ is the "completion" of $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})\otimes\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$, in the sense that:

Does $\mathsf{ZFC}$ proves or disproves that every subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is the union of a set in $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})\otimes\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ and a $2$-dimensional Lebesgue null set?

Note that the above link proves that it is consistent with $\mathsf{ZFC}$ that no well-ordering (viewed as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$) of a non-null Lebesgue measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ belongs to $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})\otimes\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$.
At last, working in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is fine, but I would also be interested to know what happens with $\mathsf{ZF}$. Thank you for any help.

Read the MathOverflow post you linked to more carefully. It already implies the answer to your question is also independent of ZFC.

@DavidGao Did you mean that the link already shows that a well-order cannot be a union of a $\nu\times\nu$-measurable set and a Lebesgue null set? Sorry for my silly question, but I didn't understand why, as Lebesgue null sets are not necessarily $\nu\times\nu$-measurable, no?

Since $\nu$ extends the Lebesgue measure, $\nu \times \nu$ extends the two-dimensional Lebesgue measure, so any two-dimensional Lebesgue null set is also null under $\nu \times \nu$, whence $\nu \times \nu$-measurable (after completion).

@DavidGao I'm confused. Of course any two-dimensional Lebesgue null set is $\nu\times\nu$-measurable after completion - that's how the completion is constructed. The problem is, even we know a well-order is not $\nu\times\nu$-measurable, how do we know that it is not $\nu\times\nu$-measurable after completion?

That’s usually what $\nu \times \nu$-measurable means. It already entails taking completions. Otherwise you could just say $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}) \otimes \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$-measurable. Regardless, you can just go through the entire proof in the linked answer. The only thing used for the measurability of the well-order is that the indicator function satisfies Fubini, which still holds after taking completions.

@DavidGao Now I understand. Thanks for the clarification!
